# .NET Core Multiple Installations

Tags: .net-core

So after multiple Visual studio upgrades, I've got several version of .NET Core some preview versions others release versions.
I notice that Ubuntu performs an in-place update so there's only one version.

Is there any need to have more than one version of .NET core installed on windows?

Comment: That sounds like one of the basic design principles of .NET Core, that you can have mutliple runtimes in parallel on one system.

Comment: @UweKeim my question is why would you?
What benefits are there to having multiple runtimes on one system

Comment: You could have application A (requiring runtime X) _and_ application B (requiring runtime Y) on the same machine.